# Caps and Num Lock Notifications in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard, windows-10, notifications, lock

A few months ago I bought a Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic keyboard. It installed some Microsoft proprietary software for itself that automatically set a notification to appear in the bottom right-hand corner of my screen every time the num or caps lock keys are pressed. I tried turning off the setting in their software which didn't work so I uninstalled their software and the device from the system.

Recently, I purchased a new SteelSeries Apex keyboard that still causes those notifications after installing the new SteelSeries drivers and it happens on any account on my Windows system. I've scoured the control panel settings and my next guess is that the problem is in the registry, but searching for "keyboard", "caps", "num", or "lock" doesn't bring me by anything obviously pertinent.

Does anyone have an idea as to how we can prevent these notifications?